# Post without title in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

In my Jekyll blog, I would like some posts not to have a title. How could I modify the Jekyll codebase to make it so that posts do not require a title?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the source and looking through it for stuff about posts?

Comment: I know very little Ruby!

Comment: That's ok, I'm sure you can pick up enough to do what you want (I don't know much Ruby either). For more details, do you mean so the filename doesn't have to be in the form `year-month-day-title`? Or so that you don't need a `title: ...` in the front matter of a post?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to alter the jekyll codebase to remove titles. That can be done using different layouts with appropriate liquid filters and tags.

For individual post pages, simply make a new layout file (e.g. "_layouts/no-title-post.html") that doesn't have the `{{ page.title }}` liquid tag. In your _posts source file, set the YAML front matter to call it. For example:

```
---
layout: no-title-post
---
```

*Note here that "title:" isn't required in the YAML front matter. If jekyll needs it, the value will be automatically crated from the filename. For example, "_posts/2012-04-29-a-new-post.md" would have its title variable set to "A New Post" automatically. If your templates don't call the title tags, it won't matter. You could include a "title:" in the front matter and it simply wouldn't be displayed.*

You can also display the page without the title in your listing/index pages. Check the posts layout to determine if the title should be displayed. For example, to show titles on all your pages *except* ones that have the 'no-title-post' layout, you would do something like this:

```
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
    {% if post.layout != 'no-title-post' %}
    <h1><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="postContent">
    {{ post.content }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

In that case, the link to the page itself is also removed. If the page needs to be addressable, you would have to add the link back in somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

**edemundo**'s solution doesn't work anymore in all cases with Jekyll 3.

I use an empty title as default:

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      type: "posts"
    values:
      layout: "post"
      title: ""
```

Then you can compare titles against the empty string in your layouts, for example:

```
{% if post.title == "" %}
    {{ post.content | strip_html | truncatewords:5 }}
{% else %}
    {{ post.title }}
{% endif %}
```

If you like the automatic title generation you can use as frontmatter:

```
---
title: ""
---
```

Comment: this worked very nicely with a jekyll / poole install.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same doubt, then I stumbled on this really simple solution:

```
{% if post.title %}
    <h1><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
{% endif %}
```

And then in the post file itself you would leave the `title` variable empty:

```
---
layout: post
title:      
---
```

This way, the `h1` will not print if the title is empty. I found this method particularly useful for post types like quotes, which most of the time doesn't have titles.